# Improper JSON data in neo4j REST api

Tags: json, neo4j, neo4jclient

Either I am missing something very obvious or there is a bug in `neo4j` REST api.
Here is a simple REST api call to create a unique user; but it fails saying Bad JSON data. Can you please provide a solution for the following?

```
http> POST /db/data/index/node/people?uniqueness=get_or_create HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 17 Accept: application/json Host: localhost:7474 Connection: keep-alive  { "phoneno" : "111" }
==> Invalid JSON data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the JSON data should be as follows instead what I have mentioned

```
{ "key" : "phoneno", "value" : "111" }
```

Personally, I feel that the need to use the text `key` and `value` is pretty redundant, and could have easily managed without it.

Comment: The thing to note is that this bag takes other values in some cases, like URI. How do you include those values, and some random key? See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M01/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-add-node-to-index